# How to exclude a source file from a Java Application project in Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

I have a Java Application project in Netbeans. I want to exclude a source file from my project (e.g. I want to keep the source file in my project but don't want to compile it).

This can be done in Visual Studio by clicking **Exclude From Project** option:

[image]

How can I do this in Netbeans?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using default Netbeans project you can configure "Includes/Excludes" patterns in project properties.

[image]

Here you can specify patterns for included and excluded source files:

[image]

Check out [Packages Includes & Excludes](http://wiki.netbeans.org/Excludes49026) on Netbeans wiki.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best actually is in project properties, then **Build -> Packaging**. There you can find the following clause already:

```
Exclude from JAR File: **/*.java,**/*.form
```

You can then just add any exclude pattern you want.